# Lattice points in spheres

Tags: analysis, number-theory, integer-lattices

Let $\mathbb{R}^n$ have the standard Euclidean metric and call a point $P = (x_1, \ldots,x_n)\in\mathbb{R}^n$ a lattice point if for all $i$, $x_i\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Allowing small number theoretic bazookas, it is not hard to see that given any $k\in\mathbb{N}$ there exists an open ball $B\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ containing exactly $k$ lattice points.

Can someone give an elementary proof of this or argue why this will have to rely on something non-elementary?

Comment: Do you consider the existence of transcendental numbers to be a number theoretic bazooka?

Comment: @ploosu2 I did and was basically looking for something that would be presentable to undergrads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the classical geometrical fact, called the *Steinhaus lattice point problem*, that given a positive integer $n$, one may find a circle on the Euclidean plane surrounding exactly $n$ points of the integer lattice. 
There is a large literature on this and its generalizations, see for example
the article

> T. Kania, T. Kochanek, [Steinhaus’ lattice-point problem for Banach spaces](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1302.6443.pdf), *J. Math. Anal. Appl.* **446** (2017), 1219–1229.

and the references therein. As far as I can see, only some elementary arguments in metric spaces are needed.